# Converting float RGBA to int RGB

Tags: c, graphics

I have a float RGBA which is from 0 to 1. I would like to convert it to int rgb

```
class Color
{
    public:
        float R, G, B, A;

        Color(float r = 1.0f, float g = 1.0f, float b = 1.0f, float a = 1.0f);
}
```

Comment: Remove the A? kappa

Comment: but I want to the equivlent int of the RGB(1,0,0);

Comment: Cast them to `int`?

Comment: RGBA is not 1 float, it's 4 floats.

Comment: int? you mean a hex color string, e.g. `#33cc66`?

Comment: Using `float` to represent pixel colors looks incredibly wrong.

Comment: sorry I meant RGBA float to 8bit RGB

Comment: Thats even more confusing

Comment: maybe 24 bit RGB?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it does that in opengl

Comment: @flatmouse sorry I meant to 8 bit

Comment: The values of RGB generally can't be floats. Don't waste your CPU cycles. But I think this is what you're looking for? ((int)r & 0xFF) << 16 | ((int)g & 0xFF) << 8 | ((int)b & 0xFF)

Comment: @flatmouse I need to convert 32bit to 8bit color

Comment: @Lupe error C2296: '&': illegal, left operand has type 'const float' and that's not to 8bit color mode

Comment: @AndreAhmed Well, that looses  much of the intermediary color values.

Comment: I want to convert the 32bit RGBA to 8bit R2G4B2

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm writing a software renderer on 8bit game console :)

Comment: I still don't see why they'd be floats

Comment: @AndreAhmed Rolled back your tag change. You cannot use `class` with c, period.

Comment: @Lupe RGBA "I still don't see why they'd be floats" Letting aside the "need" in the current context (unessential for the question) representing color component as floats in `[0...1]` is not unusual - GPU's routinely use them (my guess textures mapped on 3D objects are easier to render when non-uniformly illuminated), other languages have support for the representation (e.g. [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color(float,%20float,%20float,%20float)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edited] due to later "I want to convert the 32bit RGBA to 8bit R2G4B2"

[Edited again] due to "I'm using it on Embedded system, so static cast is not allowed"

[edited even more] due to "I'm using a c99 compiler" - so no C++

```
struct Color
{
        float R, G, B, A;
}

int RGBAstructTo8bitRGB(const Color* color) {
    if(NULL==color) { return 0; /* black */
    unsigned r=(int)(3*(color->R < 0 ? 0 : this->R));
    unsigned g=(int)(7*(color->G < 0 ? 0 : this->G));
    unsigned b=(int)(3*(color->B < 0 ? 0 : this->B));
    return (r<<6) | (g<<2) | b;
}
int RGBATo8bitRGB(float R, float G, float B) {
    unsigned r=(int)(3*(R < 0 ? 0 : this->R));
    unsigned g=(int)(7*(G < 0 ? 0 : this->G));
    unsigned b=(int)(3*(B < 0 ? 0 : this->B));
    return (r<<6) | (g<<2) | b;
}

void 8bitRGBtoRGBAstruct(int color, struct Color* dest) {
  if(NULL!=dest) {
    dest->R=(float)((color & 0x03)/3.0);
    dest->G=(float)(((color >> 2) & 0x07)/7.0);
    dest->B=(float)(((color >> 6) & 0x03)/3.0);
  }
}
```

---

For a 24-bit RGB:

Ignore `A`, scale the components to `[0,255]`, shift-or them into an int:

```
class Color
{
    public:
        float R, G, B, A;

        int toRGB() const {
          unsigned r=(int)(255*(this->R < 0 ? 0 : this->R));
          unsigned g=(int)(255*(this->G < 0 ? 0 : this->G));
          unsigned b=(int)(255*(this->B < 0 ? 0 : this->B));
          return (r<<16) | (g<<8) | b;
        }
}
```

Comment: I'm using it on Embedded system, so static cast is not allowed

Comment: @AndreAhmed I see no relation between those two statements. How does an embedded system prevent static casts?

Comment: @AndreAhmed _" Embedded system, so static cast is not allowed"_ Huh what??

Comment: and I need it R2G4B4

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm using a c99 compiler

Comment: @AndreAhmed _"I'm using a c99 compiler"_ So why you're asking for c++ then actually?

Comment: You're using C++ classes in C99? Good.

Comment: @DeiDei That looks like completely confused crap for me right now. Close to trolling. Just let's close and remove it.

Comment: I missed the tag, I will remove it

Comment: I am thinking the same. Floats used to not lose detail, but then the colors can only be 8 bits total?

Comment: In the function, if 8 bits leads to 255*, then  2* and 4* should probably be 3* and 15*.

Comment: @AndreAhmed Even if you misplaced `c++` tag as you said, your code already uses C++.

Comment: And here I thought C was a highly evolved, classless society.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I need also to convert from 8bit value to 32bit rgb

Comment: I'm simulating the code on a PC using C++. but Actually I'm running it on embedded c microcontroller

Comment: @Adrian Colomitchi how about going back from 8bit to 32bit RGB float from 0 to 1

Comment: Thanks it WORKED! :)

Comment: @Adrian Colomitchi, If I have RGB(1,0,0), then the result conversion is 192. Is that correct ?

Comment: Oh, come on @AndreAhmed! Start doing it yourself on paper if necessary. Don;t make ne feel sorry about giving you a fish instead of teaching you how to fish. (RGB(1,0,0) should result in binary `1100000`, max red and the rest are 0, right? What's the decimal for `1100000`?)

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi but using your code, it outputs 192 instead of 96

Comment: @AndreAhmed My fault in the comment: is 2 ones followed by 6 zeroes, not only 5) You asked for `R2G4B2` -so max red is 3 decimal=`11` binary. - followed by 4 zeroes for green and 2 zeroes for blue. Your fault: you are still not doing it on paper - otherwise you would have caught my error.